# How to whitelist CS 1.6 in ConfigServer Firewall

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike

I have pretty much whitelisted [all known steam ports](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711) but people still can't join my server when ConfigServer Firewall is active. Anybody knows how?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about whitelisting ports on a specific model of firewall.  This is a general firewall issue, not a gaming problem.

Comment: @badp No, this is configuring the firewall, as is rather evident by the question.  If you think it's for getting the game to work, then we need an Unclear close vote because there's not enough information to answer that.

Comment: @Frank then it would be useful to ask IMB for additional information that might help troubleshooting? Posting the firewall configuration, for example, would help.

Comment: @badp I think it's about configuring a firewall.  That's off-topic for us, so I see no need to ask for more information.

Comment: @IMB (OP) you note you're configuring the firewall but which firewall? Modern Operating systems have firewalls and routers also have firewall. If you have a router connected to a router, then you have two firewalls. I'm sure you get the picture. But can you note which firewalls you have tweaked and any complexity in your network....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about GoldSrc games, but **by default** Source Games use the following ports:

- `27015` TCP - Used for RCON.  Overridden using `-port` or `+port`.
- `27015` UDP - Used for [getting information about the game server](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries).  Overridden using `-port` or `+port`.
- `27005` UDP - Clients communicate with the server on this port.  Overridden using `-clientport` or `+clientport`.
- `27020` UDP - HLTV / SourceTV / DOTA TV listen for connections on this port. Overridden using `+tv_port` or disabled entirely using `-nohltv`.
- `26900`/`26901` UDP - Communication with the Steam backend.  This replaces the old master server query port.  Supposed to be 26900, but *some* Source games (read: most Source games) have an off by one error and actually use one port higher.  Overridden using `+steamport`